# Hiding left hand navigation menu

Tags: javascript, navigation, css

I'm using the following code to hide the left hand navigation in SharePoint:

```
<style type="text/css">
 #s4-leftpanel {
    display:none !important;
 }
 .s4-ca{
    margin-left:0px !important;
 }
</style>
```

This works great but the issue is when the page loads you can initially see the left hand menu for a few seconds but the code kicks in and it gets hidden. I don't want to see the menu on page load for a few seconds. Is that possible?

EDIT: I should have mentioned more details. I'm doing this within a custom web part. I only want the left hand navigation gone when this web part is applied to a page. I put this CSS within the web part itself.

Comment: How did you apply the CSS code?

Comment: Through a custom web part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should insert your style inside "head" tag of page.

By the code you can do it so:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<style type=""text/css""> #s4-leftpanel {display:none !important;} .s4-ca{ margin-left:0px !important;} </style>"));
```

Comment: I should have mentioned more details. I'm doing this within a custom web part. I only want the left hand navigation gone when this web part is applied to a page. I put this CSS within the web part itself. I updated the original question to reflect this.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Cheers! I had to wrap the CSS elements with a <style> tag but it worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sure. I have forgotten about style tag, sorry. :)